# How can I format my golang error logging so Google Cloud StackDriver identifies and parses it on GCE?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I've been trying to get StackDriver Error Reporting working on my golang project.
I'm running the logging agent on a vm in GCE. No matter what patterns I try it does not seem to pick it up, though it has picked up random bits of some of the stack traces, that seem to be something like

```
/^go:.*/
```

Below is an example of an error that Stack Driver picked up, and how it was mangled.

**Raw Tab**

`router.go:16: goroutine 47 [running]:
github.com/org/repo/baserouter.RecoverFromPanic.func1.1(0x15267e0, 0xc420056340)
    /home/myuser/go/src/github.com/org/repo/baserouter/router.go:14 +0xe2
panic(0xf6c320, 0xc4200120b0)
    /opt/go-1.7.1/src/runtime/panic.go:458 +0x271`

**Title**

`go: 16`

**Parsed Stack Trace Tab**

"not available"

How can I log out an error and a stack trace via the agent so StackDriver picks it up and parses it properly?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late for an answer, but since I stumbled upon this while searching myself: the steps to take to make stackdriver logging automatically trigger error reporting are detailed in [here](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/formatting-error-messages).
Because the unspecified "stacktrace detector" won't catch go errors as proper stack traces, you can add a `"@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.devtools.clouderrorreporting.v1beta1.ReportedErrorEvent"` key/value pair to your log (assuming you use json logging and not text logging.

Unfortunately for myself, I also discovered that this feature is [incompatible with regionalized log buckets](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/routing/overview#regionalization), which in my case was a deal breaker.